# What does this syntax mean in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I may not have it correct, but I saw something like this above a WebMethod:

```
[return:(XmlElement("Class2"),IsNullable = false)]
public Class2 MEthod1()
{

}
```

I saw a vb version first and I used a converter to convert it to c#.  I have never seen it before. It's in a vb 6 asmx file.

Comment: Was going to post an answer breaking down all the different parts, but I assume you're talking about "return:"?  If so, see the answers provided.

Comment: @Hans What are you talking about? [WebMethod] [return:XmlElement("GetChanged")] public string Get() { return ""; } Indeed serializes differently than without the return attribute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an attribute target, and it's being used in your example to disambiguate usage on the return value from other elements:

```
// default: applies to method
[SomeAttr]
int Method1() { return 0; } 

// applies to method
[method: SomeAttr]
int Method2() { return 0; } 

// applies to return value
[return: SomeAttr]
int Method3() { return 0; }
```

When creating attributes you can specify which language elements an attribute can be applied to. This is illustrated in the example below.

For a list of available targets see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx

```
namespace AttTargsCS 
{
    // This attribute is only valid on a class.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class ClassTargetAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    // This attribute is only valid on a method.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class MethodTargetAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    // This attribute is only valid on a constructor.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Constructor)]
    public class ConstructorTargetAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    // This attribute is only valid on a field.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
    public class FieldTargetAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    // This attribute is valid on a class or a method.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ClassMethodTargetAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    // This attribute is valid on any target.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class AllTargetsAttribute : Attribute {
    }

    [ClassTarget]
    [ClassMethodTarget]
    [AllTargets]
    public class TestClassAttribute {
        [ConstructorTarget]
        [AllTargets]
        TestClassAttribute() {
        }

        [MethodTarget]
        [ClassMethodTarget]
        [AllTargets]
        public void Method1() {
        }

        [FieldTarget]
        [AllTargets]
        public int myInt;

        static void Main(string[] args) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: James, can you elaborate a little bit. I am still slightly confused.  In my question, Class2 is a auto-generated class from an xsd file.

Comment: @Xaisoft: An attribute target defines what an attribute is being used for. Some attributes can be used on any element (class, method, return value, etc.), whereas others attributes can only be used on specific elements. In the example code you posted, the attribute can be used on a number of elements, so assigning a target disambiguates the usage on one element from another.

Answer (score 5):

It's an attribute modifying how the return value of the method is serialized into XML.

In general, the `[return: Attribute]` syntax is used to indicate that the attribute applies to the return value of a method.

Comment: John,  can you elaborate a little bit.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. You _gave_ an example.